# Can't connect between two virtual machines (No route to host)

Tags: networking

Our sysadmin created for me two CentOS virtual machines, 10.132.67.18 and 10.132.67.19. I can ssh to both of them, but when I try to network them together, I get "no route to host":

```
root@10.132.67.19:/# ssh 10.132.67.18
ssh: connect to host 10.132.67.18 port 22: No route to host
```

Interestingly, ping works:

```
root@10.132.67.19:/#$ ping 10.132.67.18
PING 10.132.67.18 (10.132.67.18) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.132.67.18: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.319 ms
64 bytes from 10.132.67.18: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.393 ms
```

This is the `iptables -S` on both machines:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.128.31.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.120.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.70.1.32/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.70.1.144/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Can it be caused by this? I don't see `10.132.67.18` listed there, and I don't know whether the default is ACCEPT or REJECT, but probably ACCEPT, based on the first lines? I am not an iptables expert....

Comment: Within a "table" the rules are applied in order. Looking at the INPUT, we see established connections are OK, ICMP (which includes ping) are OK, things coming from 10.128.31.x, 10.120.x.x and a couple of UDP things are OK, otherwise they are rejected. This includes things from 10.132.67.{18,19}. Probably best to add more rules to allow 10.132.67.x to communicate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any `ACCEPT` rule for the 10.132.67.X hosts or network, so the ssh connection satisfies the rule `j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`. That is why you see the *no route to host* message. Ping is accepted in the `-p icmp -j ACCEPT` rule, which is applied for all sources.